# Returning a string value to a parameter with lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda

I am doing a data generation project for football bettings and it works. To avoid using switch cases(as there is a huge amount of fixtures generated) I have used lambda expressions to simplify things. However I'm fairly new to Java and got stuck.

I would like to match League names to league fixtures...

eg. Liverpool - Man utd should return Premier League
while
Barcelona - Real Madrid should return La Liga

```
public static String english() {return "Premier League";}
public static String spanish() {return "La Liga" ;}
public static String french() {return "Ligue 1";}
public static String german() {return "Bundesliga";}
public static String italian() {return "Seria A";}
```

The values used for the lambda expressions are generated from here using fluttercode to generate fixtures.

```
String match = df.getItem(StaticTestData.match, 80, "Liverpool vs Manchester Utd")
```

I have used lambda expressions comparing part of string with .when()

```
DefineLeague.of(match)
                .when("Arsenal", () -> english()).when("Bournemouth", () ->english()).when("Burnley", () -> english())
                .when("Chelsea", () -> english()).when("Crystal Palace", () -> english())
                .when("Everton", () -> english()).when("Hull City", () -> english()).when("Leicester City", () -> english())
                .when("Liverpool", () -> english()).when("Manchester City", () -> english()).when("Manchester Utd", () -> english())
                .when("Middlesborough", () -> english()).when("Southampton", () -> english()).when("Stoke City", () -> english())
                .when("Sunderland", () -> english()).when("Swansea", () -> english()).when("Tottenham", () -> english())
                .when("Watford", () -> english()).when("West Brom", () -> english()).when("West Ham Utd", () -> english());
```

And should return to

```
String leagueName = ;
```

The DefineLeague class is as follows:

```
package com.sportsRecommendationsData.data.dataGeneration;

public class DefineLeague {

private static final DefineLeague DEFINED_LEAGUE = new DefineLeague(null) {
    @Override
    public DefineLeague when(String subString, Runnable r) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void orElse(Runnable r) {

    }
};

private final String str;

private DefineLeague(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}

public DefineLeague when(String subString, Runnable r) {
    if(str.contains(subString)) {
        r.run();
        return DEFINED_LEAGUE;
    }
    return this;
}

public void orElse(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
}

public static DefineLeague of(String str) {
    return new DefineLeague(str);
}

}
```

I would gladly appreciate any guidance on how to pass on the static values to parameter leagueName as I got stuck and I'm not sure I have done proper coding. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use an enum rather than lambdas?  `leagueName` could be a field of the enum, and ENGLISH, FRENCH and so on could be the enum values.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I've never seen code like this and I can't follow it. I suspect you need to use a `Map` of country to league name, and give teams a country attribute. Then your code would look something like `String leagueName = map.get(team.getCountry());`. Or you could go a little further and have `Country` and `League` classes, so `String leagueName = team.getCountry().getLeague().getName();`

Comment: Incidentally, this type of program should really be backed by a database, instead of having loads of hard-coded strings.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using a monad here, since the result can only have 1 type. Indeed, you should switch to a `Map<Team, League>`.

Comment: Even a `switch` statement will look cleaner than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Holger That is what I actually did and worked perfectly fine. I am still a student and always learning. The correct implementation is below;

```
public static String generateLeague(String match) {

  String club = null;
  String league;
  if (match.toLowerCase().contains(" ")) {
    club = match.toLowerCase().substring(0, match.indexOf(" "));
  } else {
    club = match;
  }
  switch (club) {
    case "arsenal":
    case "bournemouth":
    case "burnley":
    case "chelsea":
    case "crystal":
    case "everton":
    case "hull":
    case "leicester":
    case "liverpool":
    case "manchester":
    case "middlesborough":
    case "southampton":
    case "stoke":
    case "sunderland":
    case "swansea":
    case "tottenham":
    case "watford":
    case "west":
        league = "Premier League";
        break;
    case "angers":
    case "bastia":
    case "bordeaux":
    case "caen":
    case "dijon":
    case "guingamp":
    case "lille":
    case "lorient":
    case "lyon":
    case "marseille":
    case "metz":
    case "monaco":
    case "montpellier":
    case "nancy":
    case "nantes":
    case "nice":
    case "psg":
    case "rennes":
    case "saint-ettiene":
    case "toulouse":
        league = "Ligue 1";
        break;
    case "alavés":
    case "athletic":
    case "atlético":
    case "barcelona":
    case "celta":
    case "deportivo":
    case "eibar":
    case "espanyol":
    case "granada":
    case "las":
    case "leganes":
    case "malaga":
    case "osasuna":
    case "real":
    case "sevilla":
    case "sporting":
    case "valencia":
    case "villarreal":
        league = "La Liga";
        break;
    case "1.":
    case "1899":
    case "bayer":
    case "bayern":
    case "borussia":
    case "darmstadt":
    case "eintracht":
    case "fc":
    case "hamburger":
    case "hertha":
    case "mainz":
    case "rb":
    case "sc":
    case "schalke":
    case "vfl":
    case "werder":
        league = "Bundesliga";
        break;
    case "ac":
    case "as":
    case "atalanta":
    case "bologna":
    case "cagliari":
    case "chievo":
    case "crotone":
    case "empoli":
    case "fiorentina":
    case "genoa":
    case "internazionale":
    case "juventus":
    case "lazio":
    case "napoli":
    case "palermo":
    case "sampdoria":
    case "sassuolo":
    case "torino":
    case "udinese":
    case "us":
        league = "Seria A";
        break;
    default: league = null;

  }

  return league;
}
```

and the output is passed on the match variable;

```
String match = df.getItem(StaticTestData.match, 95, "Liverpool vs Manchester Utd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using runnable here?  Runnables are used for multithreading and do not return a value.  A better choice would be a `Supplier` which is a functional interface that takes no inputs and returns a result

you probably want to write `when` like this

```
public DefineLeague when(String subString, Supplier<String> s) {
  if(str.contains(subString)) {
    return new(DefineLeague(s.get()));
  }
return this;
}
```